# Reminder Push notification using SpringBoot and React Native

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native, design-patterns, push-notification

I have a usecase to be Implemented where I need to send Push Notification from my server which is implemented in SpringBoot.
In my case User will set a date reminder date (from mobile Application which is developed in `React Native`) which will be saved in my database `mysql`.

Now I need to check those dates (On server)and send a push notification to the users on that date.
what my guess is I need to continuously check for the reminder date for every user and if reminder date is equals to todays date then send the push notification.

But this approach I don't feel it's good.

Can anyone help me out what should be the architecture for my usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is generating the time the notification should fire, then don't have the server send a push notification. Use a local notification instead.

You can still send something to your server so that it knows a local notification was scheduled if that is data that you will either want or need to do something with, but why go through all the extra code to send a push notification when a local notification should work fine.

If the notification needs to contain some information from your server, I would try to setup your app to notify the server that a notification needs to be setup, request whatever information it will need to show, and then when the request comes back setup a local notification with the proper information.

I think there are even ways to have silent notifications that could fire and grab data from the server and then schedule an immediate local notification to show time sensitive information - assuming you can't request the appropriate information earlier.

Comment: That's great it will make my life easier.thanks for the information

Comment: My app is generating time for the notification so that will be easy for me to setup a local notification

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.